# String in scanf not visible in command line

Tags: c, command-line

I am writing a basic function in **C** on **Visual Studio Code** and while taking input from the user using `scanf`, the string in `scanf` is not visible on the *command line*. It just shows a blank space. I wanted to let the user know that they are supposed to enter an input.

```
#include<stdio.h> // header files 

void main()
{
    printf("\n   Please select the number of Players:\n");
    printf("   1. Single Player - V/S AI (in development)\n");
    printf("   2. Two Player Game - V/S Friend \n");
    int no_of_players;
    scanf("Enter %i",&no_of_players);
    printf("\n You selected, %i", no_of_players);
}
```

This is the compiler, `if ($?) { gcc tic_tac_toe.c -o tic_tac_toe } ; if ($?) { .\tic_tac_toe }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string in `scanf` is not a prompt.  It is a format string specifying what the user should enter.  In this case, it says that the string "Enter " must be typed in followed by an integer.

What you want instead is to use `printf` to print any string you want displayed and have `scanf` contain just the format specifier.

```
printf("Enter: ");
scanf("%i",&no_of_players);
```

Comment: That cleared up everything. Thanks!